# Mutating variable after ownership transfer

Tags: rust, transfer, ownership

I know how to make code work I'm just wondering why is it so.

Suppose the following program:

```
fn dummy(name: String) {
    let last_name = " Wang".to_string();
    name.push_str(&last_name);
    println!("Hello, {}", name);
}

fn main() {
    println!("What is your name?");
    let mut name = String::new();
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut name).expect("Couldn't read input!");
    name.pop();
    dummy(name);
}
```

When trying to compile it the following error occurs:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `name` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
 --> print.rs:3:5
  |
1 | fn dummy(name: String) {
  |          ---- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut name`
2 |     let last_name = " Wang".to_string();
3 |     name.push_str(&last_name);
  |     ^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0596`.
```

I know that just adding `mut` next to `name` in function definition solves this problem, but why need for declaring it as mutable in function definition when variable `name` was defined as mutable previously inside of `main` function?

Shouldn't the compiler know that variable was mutable before and why can't it transfer ownership and mutable "property" along with it?

Maybe this is stupid question but I'm new to Rust. If it behaved so would it introduce possibility for some new problems/bugs? If yes, can you give some examples?

Comment: Mutability is variable-level, not type-level, so the previous mutability doesn't matter. `name: String` essentially means "I'll take a `String`, and it'll be immutable"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that `name` is passed as a parameter is just a detail.
In this simplified example, we can reproduce the same effect.

```
fn main() {
    let mut name1 = "first".to_owned();
    name1.push_str(" second");
    let mut name2 = name1;
    name2.push_str(" third");
    let name3 = name2;
    // name3.push_str(" fourth"); // rejected
    let mut name4 = name3;
    name4.push_str(" fifth");
    println!("{}", name4);
}
```

Ownership of the string changes from `name1` to `name2`, `name3` then `name4` and each of these variables (bindings) decide (with or without `mut`) if the string, of which it is now the sole owner, can be mutated.

Initialising the parameter of a function is similar to initialising another variable (borrowing/ownership-transfer/copy...) and once inside the function the parameter is seen as any other local variable which may be mutable or not in this context.
If you intend to modify this parameter you can either declare it with `mut` or transfer it to another local variable declared with `mut`.

Note that we are dealing with **values** here, not references.
Of course, you cannot initialise a `&mut T` from a `&T`.
But prepending `mut` on a reference (as in `mut &T` or `mut &mut T`) offers the ability to reassign this reference towards another value (considered mutable or not, depending on the right `mut`).
If you are familiar with C or C++, this is similar to using `const` before or after the star (or both sides of) when declaring a pointer.

In short, using `mut` on a variable is relative to *your intention* to modify what is stored in this variable in your algorithm, but it is not a property of the content of this variable.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @prog-fh's answer, one important feature of Rust is that it allows *local* reasoning. In other words when you look at a definition, you should have all the information you need to determine if the code is correct and what it may or may not do. In your case that means it doesn't matter how `dummy` will be called and what parameters it will be passed, its definition must be able to stand on its own. So you should be able to know all there is to know about it by just looking at this part of the code:

```
fn dummy(name: String) {
    let last_name = " Wang".to_string();
    name.push_str(&last_name);
    println!("Hello, {}", name);
}
```

This makes it easier to write code as a team when using functions written by someone else, or to maintain the code in the long run when you might not remember all the details from when you initially wrote a piece of code.